# React native react-addons-perf Import Problem

Tags: react-native, package, importerror

I want to log the run times of functions in the react native project. so I want to use the "react-addons-perf" library. However, I get this error when I try to integrate.

error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-addons-perf` from `/Users/XXX/settingsScreen.tsx`: Module `react-addons-perf` does not exist in the Haste module map

yarn add @types/react-addons-perf (Using typescript)

import Perf from 'react-addons-perf'; doesnt't work

import Perf from "ReactPerf"; also doesn't work

I'm open to suggestions for solutions or an alternative library.

React native version: react-native@^0.59.9:

Comment: Could you try `var Perf = require('react-addons-perf');`?

Comment: or RealPath `import Perf from 'react-native/Libraries/Renderer/src/renderers/shared/ReactPerf';`

Comment: i tried, does not work in two methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of React 16, react-addons-perf is not supported. Please use your browser’s profiling tools to get insight into which components re-render.

Comment: in fact, instead of seeing them from the console, my goal is to save these logs, for example

Perf.start ()
return a + b;
Perf.stop ()
logger.trace(perf.getlastmeasurements()) etc. 
So, I need a log a function ms return type

Comment: Yeha but my comment goes from react documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/perf.html and in this case on React 16 + it simply not avalible

Comment: Thank you for the information, which library do you recommend to use to measure runtime of functions?

Comment: I would use browser profiling + things described here :) https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#profiling-components-with-the-chrome-performance-tab

Comment: thanks, I think browser profiling is not the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/nolanlawson/marky solved my problem thanks for all  suggestion